# How to compensate for an unstable wifi connection in Ubuntu? (Many lost packets and timeouts)

Tags: networking, wireless, firefox, internet, ping

My wifi connection usually works fine, but sometimes it becomes unstable. Many dropped pings, delays (up to 2000 ms) and sometimes duplicates. Sometimes wget can't resolve DNS or it displays a speed of 5-10 KB/s. Firefox and even Lynx often time out and downloads fail.

It's a shared connection and I can't change the router (move it, change channel, connect ethernet cable, etc). I guess it could be due to high load or maybe overlapping channels, but I can't do anything about this. Wifi networks in other places work perfectly, but I only have access to this network during the day.

Slow internet is fine. What's annoying is when tabs time out and I need to reload them again from scratch. It can take multiple reloads to access one page.

`wget --continue` helps a lot with downloads. I tried to change `network.http.connection-timeout` and `network.http.connection-retry-timeout` in Firefox to 300 seconds, but it didn't seem to affect anything. I would like Firefox to keep trying and resend lost packets if necessary, until it has loaded everything.

Are there any Firefox or Ubuntu config changes or software that can make an unstable connection more usable?

Comment: It seems your question is mostly pertaining to firefox. Are you sure that you are adjusting the right value in `about:config`? A few search results for "increase firefox timeout" suggest that you need to change `network.proxy.failover_timeout`.  But firefox has changed a lot over the years.  Maybe search the term `timeout` in `about: config` and then research each value that you find to determine what it does before you change it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the dropouts are due to the NIC invoking power saving. The first thing to try in order to stabilise your connection is to turn off power saving. In a terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

The above will change the default power saving mode for your WIFI adapter. To revert the change, just swap the positions of `3/2`.